# Telerik Reporting error - The source of the report definition has not been specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-reporting

I have viewed related posts regarding this Telerik reporting issue, but the error has not been resolved.

When I click my "Search" button, I am supposed to display data in a Telerik Reportview control. However, I get the message  ***The source of the report definition has not been specified.***

In my Telerik.Reporting.Report page, I have a Telerik.Reporting.SQLDataSource control that has a valid connection string value, along with a valid parameters value and a SelectCommand value to a stored procedure.

In the Telerik.Reporting.Report page, the properties window displays a valid value for the DataSource along with ReportParameters.

So I am providing an accurate report source.

What else could be causing the data to not display?

**Update**
I can see the data perfectly fine in Preview and HTML mode in the reportviewer design time

The code that calls the report is:

```
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        AssignedTripLog MyTripLog = new AssignedTripLog();
        MyTripLog.ReportParameters["Driver"].Value = lbDriver.SelectedValue;
        this.TripLogReportViewer.Report = MyTripLog;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are in debug mode try to restart VS otherwhise delete the data source and make a new one.It worked for for me. I never experienced it in production.

Comment: Tried both before posting..... no luck

Comment: May be obvious but....when you create the datasource, can you query the DB?

Comment: yes, I can query the DB perfectly. I can see the data perfectly fine in Preview and HTML mode in the reportviewer design time (forgot to mention that), but I cannot see the data when I run my application.

Comment: Are you working on the stand alone tool or in visual studio? Looks like there is nothing wrong with the report since you can run it but more with the rendering of the report in the report viewer. May be useful to post the code you use to render the report in your app. and to check if the class library containing the report has problems in the app.config which conflict with the app/web config of your application. Try to add a simple report to the same class library and visualize it.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008. You would be correct that there is nothing wrong with the reportviewer, it's just that I am not able to see the data when I run my application. Just updated the post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40574/discussion-between-felicem-and-csharp)